# Conditional Formatting using a Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

How to set conditional formatting to paint the row alternately using a script, for example.
the range A4: 09, paint A4, A6, A8, without using a for loop, DoWhile etc. only with an instruction, is this possible?
As doing row by row takes a long time and over the 6 minutes running the script.

Comment: Post some code that you have tried.

Comment: Please include your source code in the question.  Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible without looping.

There *are* three variations of the `offset()` method:

- offset(rowOffset, columnOffset)
- offset(rowOffset, columnOffset, numRows)
- offset(rowOffset, columnOffset, numRows, numColumns)

Which can return a range relative to some range, but there is no parameter for alternating at some set iteration.  So, you would still need to loop through the code.

Comment: as he stated that the maximum time has reached, he must be doing .setBackground() with just a value instead of .setBackgrounds() with an array...

Answer (score 0):

> without using a for loop, DoWhile etc. only with an instruction, is this possible?

Yes, though does not require a script either. Select range to be formatted (not sure whether A4:A9, Rows4:9 or maybe one or other onwards), Format, Conditional formatting..., **Custom formula is**:

```
=iseven(row())
```

and select formatting of choice.

Alternatively, you might find the `Alternating colours...` feature (within Format) sufficient.